# Python 3 Metric Conversion Project Syntax Error

Tags: python, data-conversion

I'm back again with the larger problem I've been having with my simple Python project. Apparently it wasn't just line 16. Something else is going on and I can't figure it out. Your wisdom is greatly appreciated.  The project code is below:

```
#Request user's name
    name = input("Hello! I'm your friendly metric conversion robot. What is your first name? ")

    #Miles to Km Conversion

    #Request miles & format for float
    miles = float(input(name + ", how many miles do you want to convert to kilometers? "))
    #Convert miles to kilometers
    milesToKm = float(miles * 1.6)
    #Display the result
    print(name + ", there are " + str(format(milesToKm,'.2f') + " in " + str(miles) + " miles, ")

    #Fahrenheit to Celsius Conversion

    #Request Fahrenheit temperature
    fahre = input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? "))
    #Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    fToC = float((fahre - 32)*(5/9))
    #Display result
    print(name + ", there are "+ str(format(fToC,'.2f')) + " Celsius in " + str(fahre) + " Fahrenheit degrees.")

    #Gallons to Liters Conversion

    #Request gallons
    gallons = float(input(name + ", how many gallons do you want to convert to liters?"))
    #Convert gallons to liters
    galToLiters = float(gallons * 3.9)
    #Display results
    print(name + ", there are " + str(format(galToLiters,'.2f')) + " liters in " + str(gallons) + " gallons.")


    #Pounds to Kilograms Conversion

    #Request pounds
    lbs = float(input(name + ", how many pounds do you want to convert to kilograms?"))
    #Convert pounds to kilograms
    lbsToKilos = float(lbs *0.45)
    #Display results
    print(name + ", there are " + str(format(lbsToKilos,'.2f')) + " in " + str(lbs) + " U.S. pounds.")

    #Inches to Centimeters Conversion

    #Request inches
    inches = float(input(name + ", how many inches do you want to convert to centimeters? "))
    #Convert inches to centimeters
    inchesToCm = float(inches *2.54)
    #Display results
    print(name + ", there are " + str(format(inchesToCm,'.2f')) + " in " + str(inches) + " inches.")
```

I get the same Traceback for a syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 310, in <module>
    sys.exit( main(sys.argv) )
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 284, in main
    dbgp.client.runWithoutDebug(args, interactive, host, port, idekey, logLevel)
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/python3lib/dbgp/client.py", line 4016, in runWithoutDebug
    h_execfile(debug_args[0], debug_args, module=main)
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/python3lib/dbgp/client.py", line 675, in __init__
    exec(contents, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 16
     fahre = input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? ")
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a parenthesis on the line above that line.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo:

```
fahre = input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? "))
```

That last `)` should be removed. And you're missing one on the above line.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the main problems were operand errors on lines 16 & 18. Needed a closing () and another declaration of float(). The correct code is below. Thank you all for your help! :)

```
#Request user's name
name = input("Hello! I'm your friendly metric conversion robot. What is your first name? ")

#Miles to Km Conversion

#Request miles & format for float
miles = float(input(name + ", how many miles do you want to convert to kilometers? "))
#Convert miles to kilometers
milesToKm = float(miles * 1.6)
#Display the result
print(name + ", there are " + str(format(milesToKm,'.2f')) + " in " + str(miles) + " miles, ")

#Fahrenheit to Celsius Conversion

#Request Fahrenheit temperature
fahre = float(input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? "))
#Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
fToC = float((fahre - 32)*(5/9))
#Display result
print(name + ", there are "+ format(fToC,'.2f') + " Celsius in " + str(fahre) + " Fahrenheit degrees.")

#Gallons to Liters Conversion

#Request gallons
gallons = float(input(name + ", how many gallons do you want to convert to liters?"))
#Convert gallons to liters
galToLiters = float(gallons * 3.9)
#Display results
print(name + ", there are " + str(format(galToLiters,'.2f')) + " liters in " + str(gallons) + " gallons.")


#Pounds to Kilograms Conversion

#Request pounds
lbs = float(input(name + ", how many pounds do you want to convert to kilograms?"))
#Convert pounds to kilograms
lbsToKilos = float(lbs *0.45)
#Display results
print(name + ", there are " + str(format(lbsToKilos,'.2f')) + " in " + str(lbs) + " U.S. pounds.")

#Inches to Centimeters Conversion

#Request inches
inches = float(input(name + ", how many inches do you want to convert to centimeters? "))
#Convert inches to centimeters
inchesToCm = float(inches *2.54)
#Display results
print(name + ", there are " + str(format(inchesToCm,'.2f')) + " in " + str(inches) + " inches.")
```